# Объект не движется

Tags: javascript, анимация

Квадрат должен перемещаться по кругу после нажатия "запустить" и остановиться на месте после нажатия "стоп".

Изначально он не двигается.

Подскажите, что не так, как исправить?

```js
    var t=0;
    st=false //остановить процесс
    
    function Start_stop()
    {   if(st)
       {    window.clearInterval(proc)    //остановиться
            st=false
            //заменить надпись на кнопке с именем В1
            document.all.B1.innerHTML="Запустить"  
       }
            else   //двигаться (запустить процесс с именем proc)
            {   proc=window.setInterval("move()",10)  
               st=true
               //заменить надпись на кнопке с именем В1
               document.all.B1.innerHTML="Стоп" 
            }
    }
    
    function move()
    {   
        var square = document.getElementById("square");
        var R = 5;
        var dx = R * Math.cos(t);
        var dy = R * Math.sin(t);
        
        var y = parseFloat(square.style.top);
        var x = parseFloat(square.style.left);

        square.style.top = y + dy + "px";
        square.style.left = x + dx + "px";

        t += 0.02;
        
    }
```

```html
<BUTTON ID="B1" onclick=Start_stop() STYLE="position:absolute; left:300;top:5">Запустить</button>
<div ID="square" style="top:50px; left:50px; position: absolute; background-color:red"></div>
```

Comment: Я откатил вашу правку, потому что после нее вопрос лишается смысла вообще. Не нужно так делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Он вполне себе движется.

просто вы забыли установить ширину и высоту для самого объекта, который будет бегать по кругу. В итоге вы по кругу гоняли пустой див шириной в 0 пикселей и высотой в 0 пикселей.

Просто установите стили объекта

```
#square{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Плюс я чуть уменьшил радиус

```
    var R = 2;
```

чтобы в сниппете выполнение нормально отображалось и чуть поправил стартовое положение элемента.

```
<div ID="square" style="top:10px; left:125px; position: absolute; background-color:red"></div>
```

```js
 var t=0;
    st=false //остановить процесс
    
    function Start_stop()
    {   if(st)
       {    window.clearInterval(proc)    //остановиться
            st=false
            //заменить надпись на кнопке с именем В1
            document.all.B1.innerHTML="Запустить"  
       }
            else   //двигаться (запустить процесс с именем proc)
            {   proc=window.setInterval("move()",10)  
               st=true
               //заменить надпись на кнопке с именем В1
               document.all.B1.innerHTML="Стоп" 
            }
    }
    
    function move()
    {   
        var square = document.getElementById("square");
        var R = 2;
        var dx = R * Math.cos(t);
        var dy = R * Math.sin(t);
        
        var y = parseFloat(square.style.top);
        var x = parseFloat(square.style.left);

        square.style.top = y + dy + "px";
        square.style.left = x + dx + "px";

        t += 0.02;
        
    }
```

```css
#square{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

```html
<BUTTON ID="B1" onclick=Start_stop() STYLE="position:absolute; left:300;top:5">Запустить</button>
<div ID="square" style="top:10px; left:125px; position: absolute; background-color:red"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Очень помогли

Comment: Не за что, тёзка. Просто когда правил форматирование решил проверить что с объектом...оказалось он крутится...сначала показалось что с позиционированием напутали, а через секунду понял что просто объект пустой.